# react no toma los import

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

Tengo un componente header el cual tiene unos botones, donde si se presiona uno deberia mostrar lo que esta en otro componente, que en este caso es un h1, todo esto lo llamo en el principal app.js, pero no aparece lo que esta en el otro componente que sería el h1, al principio tuve problemas con importar los componentes, pero se soluciono colocando export al inicio de las funciones.

header.js

```
    import React from 'react'
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom'

export const Header = () => {
  return (
    <header>
        <div className='container'>
            <div className='inner-content'>
                <div className='brand'>
                    <Link to= "/">Watch List</Link>
                </div>
                <ul className='nav-links'>
                    <li>
                        <Link to= "/">Watch List</Link>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <Link to= "/watched">Watched</Link>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <Link to= "/add" className='btn'>+ Add</Link>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </header>
  )
}

export default Header
```

App.js

```
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Routes, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import { Header } from './components/Header';
import { Watchlist } from './components/Watchlist.js'
import { Watched } from './components/Watched.js'
import { Add } from './components/Add.js'
import "./lib/font-awesome/css/all.min.css"
import './App.css';

function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <Header>

        <Routes>
          <Route exact path='/'>
            <Watchlist />
          </Route>

          <Route  path='/watched'>
            <Watched />
          </Route>

          <Route path='/add'>
            <Add />
          </Route>
        </Routes>

      </Header>
    </Router>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Puedes probar esto 
```function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <Header />
      <Routes>
        <Route exact path='/' element={<Watchlist />} />
        <Route path='/watched' element={<Watched />} />
        <Route path='/add' element={<Add />} />
      </Routes>
    </Router>
  );
}
```